# How to create hashMap that has a list of hashmap in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, hashmap

> What I am trying to achieve is is a map that has a list of maps in which the first key is ID and value obviously is a map of which the key is Session and the value is an OBJECT.

```
var newSession = ConcurrentHashMap<String, ConcurrentHashMap<WebSocketSession, String>>()
```

What if I want to save multiple session maps with the same ID? Whenever I pass an ID I want to get a map from which I should be able to search a particular session?
Sorry for not being so clear, but I am stuck here for a while and am kinda newbie in Kotlin!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just make the value a MutableList

Comment: Thanks man it worked I thought when I pass id key I would get That inner value of String as a list @BrettJeffreson